# Include projects as modules with relative path

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to include external projects as modules in my app, but I want their path to be relative.

What I've tried is the following:

`settings.gradle`

```
include ':MyLibrary1'
project(':MyLibrary1').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '..\\Library\\MyLibrary1')
include ':MyLibrary2'
project(':MyLibrary2').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '..\\Library\\MyLibrary2')
include ':MyLibrary3'
project(':MyLibrary3').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '..\\Library\\MyLibrary3')
include ':MyLibrary4'
project(':MyLibrary4').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '..\\Library\\MyLibrary4')
```

`build.gradle`

```
compile project(path:  ':MyLibrary1')
compile project(path:  ':MyLibrary2')
compile project(path:  ':MyLibrary3')
compile project(path:  ':MyLibrary4')
```

But I get this error: `Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.`

[image: Gradle]

Comment: Can you post the structure of your project? is there a module build.gradle file inside the library folder?

Answer (score 2):

> Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found

It happens when gradle is looking for a module `build.gradle` and it can't find it.

Make sure that you are referring **to the module inside the Library not the root folder.**

```
MyLibrary1
|--settings.gradle
|--build.gradle
|--module
|----build.gradle
```

If you have a structure like this you have to refer to `\\Library\\MyLibrary1\module` instead of `\\Library\\MyLibrary1`

In your `settings.gradle` use:

```
include ':MyLibrary1'
project(':MyLibrary1').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '..\\Library\\MyLibrary1\module')
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this you must follow this step:

1. Open your project in Android Studio
2. Go to File > Import Module and import the library as a module
3. Go to File > Project Structure > Modules
4. Locate your main project module, click on it. It should have a few
   android libraries, such as: support-v4, etc.
5. Click on the more on the left green "+" button > Module dependency
6. Select "your Library"

or follow Androd's [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-app-module.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can make the projects work when I include the full path as to where they are located. But can I somehow put some sort of `relative path` so when other people open it, it doesn't require my directory?

Comment: of course you can do this using this approach or using your module as a library github by its link github

Comment: When I try to import a module, it says this location is already imported.