# Resolve Gradle Dependencies for a Multi-project Android Application

Tags: java, android, gradle, build.gradle

I am trying to create a separate project to hold some common files that I use in multiple apps.

I am following this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601299/how-to-create-a-library-project-in-android-studio-and-an-application-project-tha), answer 3 by *Aqib Mumtaz*, to include the library project in my new app.

*I want the ability to edit the shared project as needed and publish to GitHub so that other projects will benefit from my changes.*

I created two brand new projects to test out this answer. I created a `libraryapp` project and set its plugin to  `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`. I then removed its `applicationID` as suggested in the same questions answer by *Jinbom Heo*.

***The Library Project***

[image]

***The Dummy App Project***

[image]

Secondly, I created a dummy app and followed the instructions in the the above answer and a comment about  including the library as a module dependency.

[image]

I then did a Gradle Sync and received the below errors.

[image]

According to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46949622/android-studio-3-0-unable-to-resolve-dependency-for-appdexoptions-compilecla?rq=1) both `build.gradle` projects should match the `buildTypes`.

Both of these are brand new project, with nothing in them other than the changes above. So the `buildTypes` match.

The `settings.gradle` for the DummyApp.

```
include ':app'
include ':libraryapp'
project(':libraryapp').projectDir = new File("../MyTestLibrary/libraryapp/")
```

Both projects are on the desktop.

***How do I resolve the dependency issues so that I can work on both projects simultaneously?***

Comment: add `settings.gradle` to the question

Comment: @Zoe please see updated question.

Comment: for a 1k user, I'd expect you'd know [not to add screenshots of code and errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors), but instead add them as text. Checking now though

Comment: Go to project view instead and find `settings.gradle` in the root project. If there are other settings.gradle files in the different modules, **remove them**. Settings.gradle belongs in the root of the project, not in a specific module (when you're dealing with multiple modules)

Comment: @Zoe thanks for the screenshot notice. I was attempting to show the file structure of the project too. I updated the `settings.gradle` file with the root `settings.gradle` of the dummy project.

Comment: First off, delete the library module in DummyApp. Since the source is retrieved elsewhere, it's just noise. And make sure you update the project structure so it isn't included

Comment: @Zoe I removed the library from DummyApps dependencies.and the Library Module is gone. While the DummyApp sync's correctly, I can't import any of the library's packages.

Comment: Try cleaning and rebuilding, and invalidating caches and restarting

Comment: @Zoe that didn't work either. Oddly, the IDE now no longer contains an "Android" project view.

Comment: Are all the modules correctly configured?

Comment: In the settings.gradle with new File("../MyTestLibrary/libraryapp/") make sure to refer to the library folder inside the library project and not the root folder of the library project. Check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46100715/2016562

Comment: Make sure the app module still is an Android module, and try replacing the plugin from library to app in the library project. Clean and rebuild both projects after that

Comment: @Zoe I appreciate your help but I can't seem to get this to work. The library shows up now in the project structure of the DummyApp and I can see and edit those files. But my DummyApp can't seem to access any of the library files. Nor can I import the package into any DummyApp file.

Comment: If I add a `public static String A_STRING =  "hello";` to the library, the DummyApp can only see it if I do an intention action and it imports `import static com.mycompany.mylibrary.TestActivity.A_STRING;`