# import project from eclipse to android studio maintaining project directory

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Finally I thought of migrating my android project from Eclipse to Android studio. But importing the project by generating gradle build file from eclipse wasn't helpful. The project structure is as in figure and these are the things I followed:
[image]

1. Generate gradle build file of project in Eclipse. Import Eclipse ADT project. As, you can see from figure Android-project is my main project containing manifest file and resources.
2. The barcode-common and common contains java classes which are required in main project(i.e. Android-Project). So, I created module or import existing module in Android Studio. In settings.gradle of main-project I written as

   include ':app', ':common', ':barcode-common'

And in build.gradle of main-project as

```
implementation project (':common')
implementation project (':barcode-common')
```

This works fine. But I dont want common and barcode-common to be inside main-project as I want to maintain the project directory as in figure. So, in settings.gradle of main-project I written as

```
include ':app', ':common'
project(':common').projectDir= new File('..\\common')
```

In this case I can't import any java class from common or barcode-common to main-project. Its not recognizing the java class.

So, any alternative or solution for this will be very helpful. I am struggling on this. Thanks

P.S: I want to maintain the project structure as shown in figure as common and barcode-common files are even shared by another project.

Comment: You may want to make 'barcode-common' and 'common' as [Android Libraries](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library)

Comment: @MorrisonChang Thanks for reply. If I make Android libraries and if I want to modify or add java class from common and barcode-common. Is it possible to do?

Comment: Think of them like separate projects, if you need to modify the code within, are the changes sharable with your other internal projects? Or can you extract your changes to a few classes which you can configure in your main project. Alternatively, this might be related: [Include projects as modules with relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46100715/295004)

Comment: @MorrisonChang They are shareable with my other projects. Suppose if I create same new methods or add new class it need t be accessed in main project even. I tried relative path, but it doesn't recognise class from that module.

Comment: Unfortunately, the implementation of shared android libraries does not justify the time and effort spent. If you want to see new classes from the library you need to make a symlink to library.arr file in your main project.